# Programmatically determine whether exceptions are enabled

Tags: c++, exception, metaprogramming

Most C++ compilers allow for exceptions to be disabled. Is there a way to determine it from the code without using compiler-specific preprocessor macros, such as _CPPUNWIND for MSVC? Ideally at compile time.

Comment: If this is an autoconf system, just have autoconf attempt to compile something with a `try` / `catch` and see if it will even compile. Visual Studio? Not sure, you're probably stuck with the macros.

Comment: Interesting question, but what use would that information be?

Comment: Hard to see the point of this.  std::bad_alloc and friends are real, whether or not you enable exception handling.  The angle of "let's do something reasonable" without exception handling enabled is a very murky one.  They bomb your program, one way or another.

Comment: A method that's not compiler-specific? Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Hans: Allowing the exception to "bomb your program" is an acceptable risk in many situations. For example, 99% of video games disable exceptions for performance.

Comment: @Peter: couldn't agree more.  The OP seems to want to do something more.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I am looking for good way to redesign a library which is used both by projects that enable exceptions and ones that disable them. Boost has its own macro for that purpose - I am looking for something that avoids preprocessor.

Comment: @Nemanja: How about using a the preprocessor as usual and just compiling two binaries? This sounds similar to debug builds of libraries that are shipped separately.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Yes, that's an obvious solution and works well. One downslide is that it is user's responsibility to set the version of the library they need. Ideally, I would lke the library to "recognize" the exception environment at compile time without additional work from the users.

Comment: @Nemanja: That looks like you could already help the users by letting the _build environment_ pick the right library, rather than the runtime. Would that suffice?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: So. if I understand you correctly, you suggest using compiler-specific macros to include the correct header file? Yes, I've thought of that, but am curious whether a similar effect could be reached via some template meta-programming trick that would work accross compilers. Anyway, if you submit your suggestion as an answer I will probably accept it unless I get a solution that is closer to what I just described.

Comment: @Nemanja: I'm not totally sure about the actual details, but clearly your `configure` or `cmake` script can figure out whether or not your platform supports exceptions, and that mechanism should just set a flag somewhere. You, the maintainer, build two binaries of the library, and the build environment just links against whichever library is most appropriate. To actually _build_ your two versions you could probably do some simple macro-based decision making.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since [WG21 in 2014](https://isocpp.org/std/standing-documents/sd-6-sg10-feature-test-recommendations), there is a recommended macro to use

```
__cpp_exceptions
```

It will have the value 199711 if exceptions are supported and the compiler conforms to C++98. Other [similar feature macros are shown here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/feature_test).

Comment: One challenge I've observed is that MSVC doesn't use these & if you disable exceptions/rtti those macros are undefined making it hard to distinguish between the two (i.e. does the compiler support __cpp_exceptions & exceptions are disabled or does the compiler not support __cpp_exceptions & we should use compiler-specific logic).

Answer (score 3):

I'd not burden the runtime with this decision at all. Instead, I'd build two libraries:

```
libfoo.a
libfoo_exc.a
```

Then I'd have my `configure` script determine whether or not we have exceptions, and set the Makefile like this:

```
ifeq($HAVE_EXCEPTIONS, 1)
  foolib=foo_exc
else
  foolib=foo
endif

libs=$(libs) -l$(foolib)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

To determine whether or not you have exceptions you could simply try to build a tiny test program with a trivial try/catch block as suggested in the comments.

To actually build your library, just write conditional code:

```
#if HAVE_EXCEPTIONS > 0
/* ... */
#else
/* ... */
#endif
```

And then build two libraries, one with `-DHAVE_EXCEPTIONS=0` and one with `-DHAVE_EXCEPTIONS=1` or something like that.

That way you have no runtime overhead, and your clients can use whichever library they prefer.

Answer (score 2):

No. Exceptions are part of C++. The fact that some compilers allow you to disable them is quite irrelevant and the Standard will not provide for you to detect if they're enabled- as far as it's concerned, they're always enabled. If you want to know about implementation-specific behaviour, the only way to go is to ask the implementation.

Comment: +1.  It seems OP's question if flawed in the first place.  It can be re-phrased as: "Can I detect compiler-specific behavior in a compiler-agnostic fashion?"

Comment: @Andre: you are free to rephrase it, but I believe I am asking a concrete and practical question.